# Linear Algebra - Subspaces, Basis, Dimension and Rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys stuck on a homework question. Looking for an explanation and solution please I am really struggling to understand this.

> Consider the following.
>   $W = \{(4t, t, −t): t\text{ is a real number}\}$
>
> (a) Give a geometric description of the subspace $W$ of $\Bbb R^3$.
>
> (b) Find a basis for the subspace $W$ of $\Bbb R^3$. (Enter each vector in the form $[x_1, x_2, \dots]$. Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)
>
> (c) Determine the dimension $W \subseteq \Bbb R^3$.

Comment: What don't you understand? What have you tried? Are you familiar with the terms & notation used in the question?

Comment: You can write $(4t,t,-t)$ as $t(4,1,-1).$ Does it help?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk I don't understand how to answer the questions, thus looking for solutions and explanations as to why they're the solutions. 

Yes I'm familiar, please don't be so condescending.

Comment: @SasanFouladi-Pour It's not about being condescending. It's hard to tell if you are looking for a hint, an explanation of the whole exercise, or explanation of the whole concept.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Well you certainly came across like that. In the question it says looking for an explanation and solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $W$ is the span of $\left< 4,1,-1 \right>$.

Thus, this subspace has only one basis vector.  what can you conclude about the geometric properties?

If a spanning set has only one vector, what is its dimension?